# Type 1 Conditional sentence

Tags: grammar

According to a grammar book named Top 20,  both the if-clause and the main clause describe situations that are or were always true in the first type of conditional sentence.

Here’s an example of conditional 1 in the past tense: **If I was late for work, *my boss got really angry at me*.**

That italicized phrase sounds a little off.

I feel like it should be: **my boss would get really angry at me**

Is this how you’d normally say it?

If not, how should I rephrase it?

Thank you.

Comment: "If I am late for work, my boss gets really angry at me."

Comment: I know that many speakers of AmE would not bother to use the modal in the main clause there, and would treat **if** as a synonym for *whenever*.  *If (whenever) I was late, my boss got angry.*

Answer (score 2):

In the past:

> *In my last job, one time I was late for work, my boss got really angry at me.*

Anytime in the past

> *If I was late for work, my boss would **get** really angry at me.*

Today:

> *If I am late for work, my boss gets really angry with me*

Later today and in the future:

> *If I am late for work, my boss will get really angry with me*